# Calculating EndDate using StartDate and DefaultDuration

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have to write a query to calculate EndDate=(StartDate+DefaultDurationDays)-1

I've tried this code but it doesn't work

```
declare @trainingstartdate datetime
    ,@trainingenddate datetime
    ,@trainingdefaultduration int
    set @trainingstartdate='2018-05-11'
    set @trainingdefaultduration=5
    set @trainingenddate =sum(training.trainingstartdate+training.trainingdefaultduration)-1
```

How can I fix it?

**EDIT:**

I've got these errors:

> The multi-part identifier "training.trainingstartdate" could not be
>   bound
>
> The multi-part identifier "training.trainingdefaultduration" could not
>   be bound

but these attributes are inside the same table (Training.Training).
I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? What's the error you are getting? Seems that you are doing an aggregate operation (sum) without a table to reference.

Comment: All what you need is called: `DateAdd`

Comment: @EzLo The multi-part identifier "training.trainingstartdate" could not be bound.
The multi-part identifier "training.trainingdefaultduration" could not be bound

But these two attributes are inside the same table (Training.Training).
I'm using SQL Server 2012

Comment: Well, you need to improve your question by adding such as information.

Comment: you must include some `select ... from` to use table fields data in your assignement...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming duration is days you may use:

```
select DATEADD(day, training.trainingdefaultduration - 1, training.trainingstartdate) trainingenddate
from training
```

if both startdate and duration should be received from table.